# Hoe do I enable multiple resource packs for datapacks on one server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-data-packs

I was having trouble trying to get my server to have multiple resource packs in one world. In my case, I have many datapacks on my server, but more than one of them require a resource pack, meaning I can’t enable multiple datapacks at once (in server.properties, there is only one line for the server resource pack) is there any solution to this issue?

Thanks